# Updating Associated Models in Rails with Turbo Frames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo-frames

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails 7 application with Turbo Frames, and i've encountered a design dilemma involving two models, Invoice and Customer. In my setup, the Invoice edit view includes a Turbo Frame using turbo_frame_tag{src="/customers?invoice_id=123"} that displays the Customer#index view (if invoice.customer is nil), complete with a "Select" button for each customer.

Here's the challenge: when a user selects a Customer, I'm currently handling this by submitting a form to invoices#update, where i updarte the @invoice.customer. However, I then want to update the Turbo Frame to show customer#show for the selected customer. This approach feels awkward because it involves rendering a Customer view from the InvoicesController. (or re-rendering my entire invoice/_form but this overwrites potential non-saved text inputs)

I've also considered updating the invoice.customer within the CustomersController#update action, but this doesn't feel right either, as it involves modifying the Invoice from within the CustomersController.

I'm seeking advice on a more appropriate or Rails-idiomatic way to handle this. How can I efficiently and cleanly manage the interaction between these two models and update the views accordingly, while adhering to good MVC principles? Is there a better pattern or strategy for handling this kind of interaction between models and views, particularly in the context of Turbo Frames in Rails?

i prefer to do it without Stimulus; Turbo Streams is maybe an option; adding an additional function/method to my InvoicesController feels also like repeating the update code :(

Comment: why can't you redirect from `InvoicesController#update` to `CustomersController#show`? [`redirect_back`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back) is also a thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wasn't aware that redirect_to could function within format.turbo_stream {... }. However, I now realize that I also need to implement a Turbo Stream response in my client#show view. I'll evaluate whether the additional effort is justified in the future.

Comment: i meant you can redirect within a turbo frame